# Getting Alert View from Facebook to login again?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am getting an alert view from Facebook to login again. Pressing ok, it takes to Fb login but I need an access token return from it how can I get.
I am not getting the code for Log in, I think Facebook internally handles it.
http://screencast.com/t/k8P8BPMy

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. Did you got the answer?

Comment: If you are using the Facebook SDK then you can get the access token by making a call to `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString`.